# How do i convert multi-byte integer values to 4bytes array using the two's compliment notation in the big-endian order

Tags: java, arrays

I need to convert integers that I send over 4bytes per socket in java. The problem is that when the integer exceeds 9, ie [10, +inf] my crash code.

I read in the instructions this line:
**All multi-byte integer values are encoded using the two's compliment notation in the big-endian order.**

The problem is that I don't know how to write the appropriate conversion function. Here is the one I had implemented and which seems to work for integers from 0 to 9. Can someone help me.

```
byte[] size_buffer = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   size_buffer[i] = (byte)(msg_size >>> (i * 8));
}
```

Comment: All Java integers are encoded in two's complement, big-endian order already.  Java `int`s are the four-byte flavor of those.

Comment: Please post code. @JohnBollinger is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByteBuffer` has nice functionality for this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
        .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) // make explicit
        .putInt(intValue);
// bytes is now updated
```

`ByteBuffer` [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) in **java SE 8**

Comment: Thank you so much. this solves my problem and even allows me to revise my code to have an even better version. Thanks to everyone else too. What will I do without stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to convert integers that I send over 4bytes per socket in java.

Probably no actual conversion is required.

> The problem is that when the integer exceeds 9, ie [10, +inf] my crash code.

Nothing in what you have presented suggests why that would be, though in fact the conversion presented is wrong.

> **All multi-byte integer values are encoded using the two's compliment notation in the big-endian order.**

This is Java's native representation for type `int`.  You can write `int`s to the socket's output stream by wrapping it in a `DataOutputStream` and using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()`.  Or if you are using NIO then you can put an `int` into a `ByteBuffer` via the buffer's `putInt()` method.  Either of these approaches sidesteps any need to manually encode integers into byte arrays.

But if you insist on doing your own conversion, completely manually, then this ...

> ```
> byte[] size_buffer = new byte[4];
> for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>    size_buffer[i] = (byte)(msg_size >>> (i * 8));
> }
> ```

... reads out the bytes in little-endian order instead of big-endian (most-significant to least).  This would be a correct alternative:

```
byte[] size_buffer = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   size_buffer[i] = (byte)(msg_size >>> ((3 - i) * 8));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You state you tried `+Inf`, but that is not an `int` value. The only number type you can stick `+Inf` into is `double` or `float`, but it's a compiler error to attempt to do `>>>` to a double or float.

Also, the code snippet you wrote doesn't work for anything - it turns things into **little endian** order. It treats 9 the exact same way it treats 10: 9 turns into [9, 0, 0, 0] (which is 9 in 2's complement int, but, **little endian**), and 10 becomes [10, 0, 0, 0].

In other words, you've either thoroughly misanalysed your own code, or you aren't running that snippet.

This will work fine:

```
int n = -2;
byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   sizeBuffer[i] = (byte)(n >>> (24 - (i * 8)));
}
```

Turns -1 into [255, 255, 255, 254] (in java bytes are rendered signed, so if you try to print that, it'll probably show as -1, -1, -1, -2. It's the same thing) - and that is indeed -2 in 2's complement big endian.

You can make a `ByteBuffer` and write that way as well.